# LTspice simulation how to multiply each list value by a variable

Tags: ltspice

I am performing an LTspice simulation. I am trying to get multiple plots. The task I have to perform is this

```
Ia = [0.1, 0.3]*Ib # Multiply each element with variable Ib
```

LTspice command

```
STEP PARAM Ia LIST 0.1*Ib 0.3*Ib
```

Present output:

```
"Cannot find 0.3*Ib"
```

Comment: Where does the value for Ib come from? Is it a .PARAM? Or somerthing else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the multiplication outside of the .STEP command.

```
.PARAM Ib = 0.1
.STEP PARAM Istep LIST 0.1 0.2 0.3
.PARAM Ia = IStep * Ib
```

Comment: [Funny thing, huh...](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/topic/question_about_param_and/89710145)

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I hadn't seen anyone try to do this before so I just opened up LTSpice and figured out how to do it, I guess if two of us came up with the same solution it must be a good one.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply anything, but the coincidence was far too striking to ignore.